# My layout background scrolls in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image

I've a RelativeLayout as my main layout for my view. I've set an image as background. I've also added a couple of EditText on that view. My problem is that when I begin editing an EditText and the keyboard is displayed, my background scrolls up. How could I solve this?
This is my RelaviveLayout definition:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPrincipal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ciudad_hd_1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Did you try setting focusableInTouchMode to off?

Comment: And what does android:orientation="vertical" does here?

Comment: Setting focusableInTouchMode=true prevents my app to open the keyboard when I run it. I've tried to switch it to false but it does not work

Comment: I've removed the android:orientation="vertical". It was there because my first layout was a LinearLayout

Comment: did u use the attribute android:windowSoftInputMode in your activity tag in the manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this in your activity Tag in th AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" . . . >
```